How to render a react functional component when instance variable of separate class instance changed?
I am trying the below code,
SubscriptionHandler.js
class SubscriptionHandler {
  constructor() {
    this.orderBooks = [];
  }
  
  recenterOrderBooks = () => {
    this.orderBooks.forEach((item, idx) => {
      // doing something
    });
  };
}

const subscriptionHandler = new SubscriptionHandler();

export default subscriptionHandler;

OrderBookHome.js
import subscriptionHandler from "../../services/SubscriptionHandler";

function OrderBookHome() {
   // some piece of code
   
   return (
     <Box display="flex" justifyContent="center">
    <AddOrderBookForm handleRecenter={subscriptionHandler.recenterOrderBooks}    />
    </Box>
   )

}

export default OrderBookHome;

AddOrderBookForm.js
function AddOrderBookForm({...otherstates, handleRecenter}) {
   // some piece of code
   
   return (
     ....code
     {condition &&
        <Button onClick={handleRecenter}> Recenter Orderbooks </Button>
     }          
     ....code
   )

}

export default AddOrderBookForm;

In this piece of code, whenever the button is clicked I want to rerender OrderBookHome component and display recent data of orderBooks from subscription handler. What is the correct way to do it?
I don't want to create a separate instance of SubscriptionHandler in OrderBookHome.

You'll need orderBooks to be state in your OrderBookHome and then update that to trigger the rerender

currently I am using subscriptionHandler instance to get orderBooks information, I don't want to create a separate state just for orderBooks, as I am using that orderBooks of the subscriptionHandler instance in multiple places. If I create a state then I need to handle both state and this.orderBooks. Is there any other solution?

The only way your component is going to rerender is if you update state. If you have orderBooks being used in multiple places, the correct way to handle that in React is to use a context + state value and then update that, or lift your state up. You can use hacks to rerender your component but wouldn't recommend it as it's not very "reacty".

My team uses the MobX library to handle this kind of thing.

@TimMoore Ok, I'll check this out
